# How to find the path through a dotted (station) path, like a metro map for example

Tags: algorithm, routes, programming-languages, dijkstra

This is the map of Metro stations, each vertical line is a line with different stations, and horizontal lines represent transferring station where you can change your line and get to another one.
[image]

I was trying to make a program that given a starting station and an ending station would return the number of stations required for the trip. I started by creating a dictionary containing the there lines and their stations numbered in order, but it ended with a lot of if statements and I couldn't figure out how to make it move from a line to another using the line-switching stations. I thought of using nodes, and Dijkstra's algorithm, but I am not sure if it would work. 
I don't know what I should look for, or which algorithm I should try. Is Dijkstra's algorithm suitable or is it more concerned about the distance between the nodes?

Comment: Any derivative of Breadth First Search will work

Answer (score 0):

You can set every distance between nodes to 1 and then Dijkstra's algorithm will apply here.